# Action of Moller operators on stable one particle states in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, s-matrix-theory

In Weinberg's book "The QFT", vol. I, it is claimed that for theories with stable single particle states the $S$-matrix maps each such state to itself (see Section 4.3, p. 179). I am wondering if the following stronger property holds.

> The $S$-matrix is a composition $S=\Omega^\dagger(+\infty)\Omega(-\infty)$ of Moller operators. Is it true that if one-particle states are stable then each operator $\Omega(\pm\infty)$ maps each such state to itself? In particular, does this property hold for fermions and photons in QED?